# can't update JDBC RowSet with Oracle Database

Tags: oracle, jdbc, rowset

I need to update some rows in a RowSet, but when I'm trying to do that I get an not updateable Exception. Why?

```
JdbcRowSet rs = new oracle.jdbc.rowset.OracleJDBCRowSet(con);
rs.setCommand("SELECT status FROM s");
rs.setUrl("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl");
rs.setUsername("username");
rs.setPassword("password");
rs.setReadOnly(false);
rs.execute();

 // this doesn't work
rs.last();
rs.deleteRow();
 // this doesn't work too
rs.absolute(2);
rs.updateInt("status", 10);
rs.updateRow();
```

Comment: What is the actual exception?  The devil is in the detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I imagine the exception you're getting is

```
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid operation for read only resultset: deleteRow
```

or something similar.  This was what I saw while testing out your code.

To be honest, I hadn't seen the class OracleJDBCRowSet used before.  I wasn't too sure how to modify your code to get around the error you saw.  However, it's not too difficult to make your code look more like 'traditional' JDBC whilst also retaining the ability to change the result-set in Java.  All you really need to do is to pass an extra two parameters to the `prepareStatement` method call:

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(
    "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:orcl", "username", "password");

Statement stmt = con.prepareStatement(
    ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_UPDATABLE);

ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT status FROM s");

/* this should work */
rs.last();
rs.deleteRow();
/* this should also work */
rs.absolute(2);
rs.updateInt("status", 10);
rs.updateRow();
```

Comment: Well, according to [documentation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/rowset.html) RowSet can be Disconnected (cachedRowSet), so it lets me modify the data without any connection, that's what I need. But thank you for help. Your code also works for me.